# Can't see graph editor bezier handles

Tags: bezier-curves, graph-editor

I'm trying to manually edit the curve but I can't access the bezier handles. I've tried zooming in, and ticking the option under the menu, both without success. Does anyone know why?

[image: missing bezier handles]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set the interpolation type to back, select the left keyframe and press <kbd>T</kbd> then select bezier.

[image: bezier interpolation]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to *hide* and *show* the handles. You can also find this setting in the view menu of the *Graph Editor*:

[image]

Comment: +1 This helped me.